# How to "Tell, don't ask" when 2 objects involves in the condition and the decision at the same time?

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, coding-style

According to [Explanation on how "Tell, Don't Ask" is considered good OO](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157526/explanation-on-how-tell-dont-ask-is-considered-good-oo), I know the following is bad:

```
if(a.isX){
    a.doY();
}

public class A{
    public boolean isX;
    public void doY(){
    }
}
```

which I should modify it to

```
a.doYWhenX();

public class A{
    private boolean isX;
    public void doYWhenX(){
        if(this.isX){
            this.doY();
        }
    }
    public void doY(){
    }
}
```

to obey "tell, don't ask" rule. But what if the situation that needs 2 objects? eg:

```
if(a.isX && b.isP){
    a.doY();
    b.doQ();
}

public class A{
    public boolean isX;
    public void doY(){
    }
}

public class B{
    public boolean isP;
    public void doQ(){
    }
}
```

How should I refactor it to obey "Tell, don't ask" rule? I tried:

```
a.doYWhenX(b);

public class A{
    private boolean isX;
    public void doYWhenX(b){
        if(this.isX && b.isP){
            this.doY();
            b.doQ();
        }
    }
    public void doY(){
    }
}

public class B{
    public boolean isP;
    public void doQ(){
    }
}
```

but A is still asking the state of B, which is not "pure tell,don't ask".

Note: In real code, A and B are some components (eg:Timer, Notice board) which the isX and doY() is not easy to move them into 2 separate classes, and A and B are not easy to combine into one class because some other classes may just use A individually instead of B, for example (which simulates an Page based app, Page1 uses both A and B, but Page2 uses A only):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    this.a=new A();
    this.b=new B();
    Page1 page1=new Page1(this.a,this.b);
    this.view.addSubview(page1);
    Page2 page2=new Page1(this.a);
    this.view.addSubview(page2);
}

public class Page1 extends View{
    private A a;
    private B b;
    public Page1(A a,B b){
        if(a.isX && b.isP){
            a.doY();
            b.doQ();
        }
    }
}

public class Page2 extends View{
    private A a;
    public Page2(A a){
        this.a=a;
    }
    public void onButtonPressed(){
        a.doX();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a _principle_, not a _rule_. You do it to the extent that you can, because it is generally a good idea, but deviating from it is not necessarily a problem, only a reason to think about it (a "code smell"). Maybe the objects belong together (maybe there should be a "higher level" object containing both), maybe not.

Comment: I think the "tell, don't ask" involves code where the *same* class has control over both checking the condition and performing the action. That's not true in your `A`/`B` example any longer.

Comment: I.e., consider the difference between `if(a.isX && b.isP){ a.doY(); b.doQ(); }` and `a.doYWhenX(); b.doQWhenP()`. You can't do "tell, don't ask" without *somebody* coordinating activity among unrelated classes.

Comment: On a slightly more fundamental level, we want to write programs that are simple. Simple often means in the graph of connections between objects we have few connections between objects and try to keep tangled connections clumped as closely as possible. "tell, don't ask" is a rule of thumb to encourage this - it reminds you that in this particular case we can get away with replacing two connections between the calling and called object with one connection between them, plus a hidden connection in the called object. But sometimes you can't get away with it, and you need the two connections.

Comment: Is this a concrete problem? Or are you thinking of theoretical examples that might pose a difficulty in parsing this guideline? Because this very much looks like a contrived example whereby the condition is only met when two otherwise unrelated objects match individual conditions which then is supposed to trigger an action in both objects. More likely than not, this is an inefficient object design to begin with, regardless of how it fits with "tell don't ask". I suspect you're either dealing with badly designed code or are working based off of an unfounded theoretical thought exercise.

Comment: The condition *if(a.isX && b.isP)* looks contrived to me. In reality it's more likely to be *if(a.isX && **b.isX**)* - in which case perhaps Class X should have a single instance of a *base* class that knows how many of itself are out there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You seem to have subtly redefined `a.isX` as `a.issubclass(X)` (or in Java, `a instanceof X`), which isn't indicated in the original question — the `a.isX` and `b.isP` booleans represent _some condition_ within the respective objects being true, but there's no indication that those checks are questions of class hierarchy/membership.

Comment: @FeRD: I have no preconceptions about exactly what "isX" means. I was primarily agreeing withj Flater's comment that the example presented here looks to be either unreasonably contrived, OR it reflects an "artefact" arising in the context of substandard system design.

Comment: Many have pointed out that "Tell, don't ask" is a principle, not a rule.  To back that up, I'd like to point out that the Visitor design pattern is quite literally the antithesis of the "tell, don't ask" principle.  The entire point of the visitor pattern is to decouple the algorithm from the data it operates on.  And its easy to demonstrate that there is a time and a place for that sort of thinking.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You wrote

> I know the following is bad

and already here is a misconception: thinking religiously in terms of good and bad about this. My interpretation of Tell-Don't-Ask is: when you see a code snippet like

```
if(a.isX){
    a.doY();
}
```

you **may consider** refactoring it to `a.doYWhenX();` - or not. But before you decide about this refactoring, also check

- whether `doYWhenX()` is a useful abstraction in your context
- whether `doYWhenX()` has some reuse potential
- whether it helps to make `a.isX` (or `a.isX()`) private
- whether it makes the using code more readable
- is it worth the hassle?

So my recommendation is to change your mindset about the "Tell-Don't-Ask principle" - it is a rough guideline, a rule-of-thumb design heuristic, nothing more.

Now apply this to your case with two objects:

```
if(a.isX && b.isP){
    a.doY();
    b.doQ();
}
```

Whether it it more suitable to refactor this

- to `a.doYQWhenXP(b);` or
- to `b.doYQWhenXP(a);` or
- to `myService.doYQWhenXP(a,b)`, or
- leave the code as it is

depends heavily on the context: which variant in your real world context creates highest readability, best reusability, most sensible abstraction, or best encapsulation. Meaningless names like `doX` or `isP` alone are not suitable for making such a decision.

Comment: Agreed. The new name having "when X" in it means that code outside the class knows the rules for when Y-ing is allowed. Bank accounts don't have "WithdrawWhenBalanceisPositive" or "WithdrawWhenNotPastOverdraftLimit" they just have Withdraw. This isn't a mechanical renaming principle, it's the idea of **moving the knowledge** about when Ying is allowed into the inside of the class that does Y. Especially when the knowledge relates to a member variable of that same class.

Comment: @KateGregory: I don't disagree, still I think we should not overinterpret the artificial, almost meaningless names the OP used for this example. I think the OP chose `doYWhenX` to make it clear there is a difference to just `doY`. In real code, they would probably choose more meaningful names.

Comment: @KateGregory: Besides the code structure, moving the check into the action also has important implications for TOCTOU

Answer (score 14):

*[**Tell don't ask**](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)* is a principle aiming at guidance for effectively encapsulating internal details of objects. It therewith:

- encourages **better abstraction**, by placing inside the object the logic that belongs to it;
- facilitates  the [principle of **least knowledge**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), by avoiding that objects need to rely unnecessarily on internal details of their neighbours.

It is however not an absolute principle and needs to be [**balanced against sound separation of concerns**](https://wiki.c2.com/?TellDontAsk) and single responsibility. In particular, when two objects of different classes are involved, it is vital not to spill unrelated concerns/responsibility into the one or the other object.

In some cases, the solution can be a **third object that encapsulates the interaction** (e.g. saving accounts and stock accounts could interact via a "transaction" object) that hides the details to the outside world with a *tell don't ask* but still internally interact with each involved object without forcing them to deal with matters not of their concern.

Comment: "In some cases, the solution can be a third object that encapsulates the interaction" – This is so often overlooked. Sometimes when you have trouble deciding which existing object to put some behavior on, the solution is: none of them. Listen to your design: if it looks like regardless of which of the two objects you put the behavior on, you'll get in trouble, the design is telling you that it doesn't belong on either of them.

Comment: That really [can't be](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/418466/118878) [stressed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/314278/118878) [enough](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/410005/118878), @JörgWMittag. A lot of design issues can be solved with a separate class that coordinates logic between other classes.

Comment: @GregBurghardt And almost as many can be created. Truly, this is a versatile technique.

Comment: All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection, except for the problem of too many layers of indirection. – David J. Wheeler

Comment: @jmoreno aren't most of the problems in computer science  solved by turning it off and on again? ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, "tell, don't ask" is a principle not a rule.  It leads your code in a direction which has some good properties, but has other quirks that sometimes you wish to avoid.

The easiest way I know of to work with such a principle is to look at the consequences.  The big consequence here is a coupling of algorithm and state.  And, the argument made by "tell, don't ask" is that this is a good and desirable thing.  It's encapsulation.  However, we can't blindly encapsulate everything.

The "tell, don't ask" can make a lot of sense when you can definitively say that there is exactly one correct way to handle any given conditional behavior.  Consider the example in the linked question with users and addresses, if you can unequivocally say that claiming a user's address is 'No street name on file' is the only correct way to handle case of asking for a non-existent user's address, and no algorithm could possibly ever want another implementation, then this pattern is great.  It encapsulates a behavior that is really closely tied to the object.

... nevermind that that string is probably not going to pass your validation algorithm that looks for a valid street address.  So we'll have to handle that case specially.  And if this were an email, rather than a street address, you'd probably have to deal with a bunch of latent bugs that manifest in your email server logs where they point out that you keep sending emails to invalid addresses.

There are times where the behavior is more tied to what you want to do with the object than to the object itself.  In these cases, it makes more sense to let the algorithm query state, and make its decisions.  This is especially true if your objects are part of a library and users are permitted to write algorithms that use said library.

Conditional logic is something that I think more-often-than-not is tied to an algorithm.  This is especially obvious after two or more algorithms want to do different things.  personally I would scream if I saw a `A` class (using your example now) which looked like

```
class A
{
    public void doX();
    public void doY();
    public void doZ();
    public void doXwhenA();
    public void doXwhenB();
    public void doYwhenA();
    public void doYwhenC();
    public void doZwhenAandBbutNotC();
    public void doZwhenPhaseOfMoonIsFull();
    public void doZifAOtherwiseDoX();
}
```

In these cases, sure, encapsulation is a good ideal.  But you encapsulated the wrong thing.  You encapsulated something that really didn't belong inside `A`'s bubble in the first place.  And now it is threating to pop `A`'s bubble outright.

Comment: Is Phase a public property of Moon?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if(a.isX){
>    a.doY();
> }
> ```

This is not a violation of "Tell, don't ask". Directly accessing the data-member `isX` is not nice, but that can be easily remedied with a accessor:

```
public class A{
    private boolean X;
    public boolean isX(){
        return this.isX;
    }
    public void doY(){
    }
}

if( a.isX() ){
    a.doY();
}
```

Asking an object for (a portion of) its state is **not** a violation of "Tell, don't ask". It **is** a violation if you start masking changes to an object or performing a calculation that can be described as an operation *of* the object. For example:

```
Point p;

// Violation
p.x = p.x + 10;

// Also violation
p.setX(p.getX() + 10);

// Good
p.move(10, 0);.
```

Coming back to your two objects example

> ```
> if(a.isX && b.isP){
>    a.doY();
>    b.doQ();
> }
> ```

That is not a violation of the "Tell, don't ask" rule. The `a.isX` and `b.isP` access to data members is a violation of encapsulation, but that can be easily resolved with accessors is each class.

Comment: It is a violation if doY() changes state. Then the code is making a decision to change state, based on its state. Wether thru a field, property or other method doesn’t matter.

Answer (score -1):

When you do decide it is worth the hassle, there is a refactoring for this that follows tell don't ask. Yes, even with two classes. Yes, without encapsulation destroying accessors. No getters required.

What you need is [multiple dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). Something which many languages don't directly support. Including Java.

You can simulate multiple dispatch in Java using a little thing called the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
class A {
    private boolean isX;

    public void accept(B b) {
        if (this.isX) {
            b.accept(A::doY);
        }
    }

    public void doY(){
    }
}
```

Do it this way and you need no accessors. `A` decides what to do based on it's own state. `B` decides what to do based on it's own state. And nothing is done until both states have had their say.

Oh sure, it's ugly. It always is when simulating a feature your language doesn't have. But if real encapsulation is important to you, done with no getters, where only `A` knows `isX` exists, then this works.

There are slicker solutions that might be viable where `A` and `B` don't even know each other exist. See [Predicates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). See also: [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/differences.html#_multi_methods). See also [getThis() trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958182/java-generics-getthis-trick-explanation).

Comment: Just looking at the code snippit from a function naming perspective, this example is either doing something brilliant or missing part of the visitor pattern, and I can't tell which.  Using the "standard" terminology from the linked Wiki page, A has an "accept" function, which means it is an Element.  "accept" takes a visitor as an argument, which means B must be a visitor.  But B also has an accept function, which takes a function as an argument (I'm guessing that's newer Java syntax than I'm familiar with), but a function isn't a visitor.  Does B have a method named "accept" (which isn't a..

Comment: .. Element accept function and thus not part of the Visitor pattern), that is doing something really clever here?

Comment: @CortAmmon Java doesn’t have multiple dispatch. Not even double dispatch. It does have single dispatch. Which you can use to simulate it. One way to do that is the visitor pattern. Control goes through single polymorphic dispatching twice. The weird wrinkle is passing the static method reference to achieve the late binding this refactoring needs. That part isn’t classic visitor. It could be done in a number of other ways.